# Parsing JUnit XML with Hudson

Tags: junit, hudson, jasmine

I'm using [Jasmine-reporters](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters) with Jasmine to output a bunch of JUnitXML format files that I need Hudson to parse for me and report on success/failure. Does anybody know how I would ask Hudson to go test a bunch of XML as part of the build process? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the job's "Post-build Actions", there should be a check box to "Publish JUnit test result report".  You can put an ant-glob expression (as if you were writing an "includes" element) to match your xml files.  I'm basing this on what I see in my Jenkins server; Hudson should be equivalent for your question.